# Сравнение двух листов google таблицы

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть 2 листа в google-таблице. В каждом листе два столбика (А-имя, B-номер телефона), в первом листе 600 строк, во втором 100 строк. Почти все строки из второго листа в том или ином месте встречаются в первом листе. Внимание вопрос:
Как сделать таблицу в которой будут строки из первого листа но без строк из второго листа? Иными словами, как удалить в первом листе строки, которые встречаются во втором листе?

Comment: В дополнительном столбце использовать ВПР(). Отсортировать по нему. Удалить существующие. Удалить доп. столбец.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого в первом листе в новой колонке - добавьте формулу:
`=VLOOKUP($B2;'Лист2'!A:B;2;0)` - и затем фильтром уберите значения где нет ошибок (ошибка появляется если значение не найдено).

Answer (score -1):

Я думаю в первую очередь стоить скопировать эти таблицы к себе на компьютер, сохранить в формате Excel и искать ответ на форумах связанных с Excel таблицами